# PDFViewer in Fragment from Master/Detail Flow

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, pdf

Использую Master/Detail Flow для выбора и чтения статей. Хочу сделать так, чтобы он мог считывать PDF файлы.
В Gradle прописал `implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.5'` и, почитав пару статей,

```
aaptOptions {
        noCompress "pdf"
    }
```

в item_detail.xml сейчас следующее:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/PDFView"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Далее после небольшой корректировки в DummyContent я внёс изменения в ItemDetailFragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_detail, container, false);
        PDFView pdfView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.PDFView);
        if (mItem != null) {
            pdfView.fromAsset(mItem.url).load();
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

В свойство url на данный момент прописан путь до .pdf файла, который расположен в assets.
Строка из DummyContent:

```
public static class DummyItem {
        public final String id;
        public final String content;
        //public final String details;
        public final String url;

        public DummyItem(String id, String content, String url) {
            this.id = id;
            //Название статьи
            this.content = content;
            //Текст статьи
            //this.details = details;
            //Путь до статьи
            this.url = url;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return content;
        }
    }
```

При тестировании с телефона с небольшим дисплеем при нажатии на любой пункт меню файл не подгружается, но при тесте с планшета на второй части экрана pdf корректно отображается и грузится мгновенно.

Также ранее пробовал конвертировать PDF файлы в HTML с помощью Adobe Acrobat, но после конвертации при попытке отображения с помощью WebView созникает сразу несколько проблем:

1. Файл конвертируется с помехами, многие элементы "съезжают"
2. Очень долго грузится

Итак, сам вопрос: могут ли возникать проблемы с отображением по причине того, что PDFViewer плохо взаимодействует с Fragment? Если да, то имеются ли какие-нибудь альтернативы, но без применения Интернета (обязательное условие)? 
Уже видел несколько вариантов обходного решения, но они все используют Интернет.

Comment: Скинь логи, exception мб........

Comment: Имеется в виду файл idea.log, который ~валяется где-то здесь \.AndroidStudio3.1\system\log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос можно считать закрытым, решение найдено.
Оказывается, NestedScrollView, который служил контейнером для фрагмента (item_detail_container), плохо совместим с PDFViewer. Так что мы заменили его на FrameLayout в файле activity_item_detail.xml - и всё заработало)
Ответ почерпнули отсюда: https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview/issues/176